# Tagging sub-trunk directory when releasing with Maven (using SVN)

Tags: svn, tags, maven, release, trunk

Here is my SVN structure :

```
trunk /
 +- docs /
 +- dev /
     +- project-parent /
     +- project-war /
releases /
```

I would like the Maven release plugin to tag `/trunk/dev/` to `/releases/<release-version>`

Here is my parent `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/project/releases</tagBase>
                <generateReleasePoms>false</generateReleasePoms>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/project/trunk/dev</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/project/trunk/dev</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

The problem is that when I execute `mvn release:prepare-with-pom`, Maven tags `/trunk` to `/releases/<release-version>`.

Does someone know how to tag `/trunk/dev` instead ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround : set `remoteTagging` to `false`

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <tagBase>http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/project/releases</tagBase>
            <generateReleasePoms>false</generateReleasePoms>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug ! I've created an issue here : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-642.